# Phusion Passenger (w/ Nginx + Rails app) won't stop spawning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

```
root@mysite:~# passenger-status
Version : 5.0.6
Date    : 2015-10-12 15:54:03 -0700
Instance: P4b1jBjU (nginx/1.6.2 Phusion_Passenger/5.0.6)

----------- General information -----------
Max pool size : 700
Processes     : 681
Requests in top-level queue : 0

----------- Application groups -----------
/opt/nginx/html/mysite/current/public#default:
  App root: /opt/nginx/html/mysite/current
  Requests in queue: 0
  * PID: 21097   Sessions: 1       Processed: 25      Uptime: 36m 2s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 119M    Last used: 35m 38s ago
......
  * PID: 20818   Sessions: 0       Processed: 0       Uptime: 4s
    CPU: 151%    Memory  : 0M      Last used: 4s ago
```

I'm running Phusion Passenger, and even when the number of active Nginx connections (as per stub_status) is far less than the Passenger active pool size, the pool keeps expanding. No matter high I set it (currently at 700 max), it keeps growing. Why would this be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved after I compiled a later version of the Passenger + Nginx combo. This occurred on a VPS that was just moved from other hardware, so the recompilation may have been the sole reason for the solution (vs. the software version upgrade).